# Docker Node: Running into `exec format error`

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy a Docker container on a Raspberry Pi 4, but I'm running into the following error: `exec format error` .

My RPi 4 runs on `linux aarch64 Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)` OS and I've got Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b installed on it.

I'm not sure what is going wrong because I'm not touching or modifying the `docker-entrypoint.sh` and last week everything was running fine.

The container itself should run a script first, which would handle running migrations for a database (MySQL) in this case. After which a NestJs back-end application should start up. This application hosts a front-end Angular application. This script is never executed because the container hangs on the executing of the `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` with the error that I've mentioned above outputted.

Related code can be found in the repository of my project, which can be found [here](https://github.com/NoNamer777/dnd-mapp)

What is even more weird, is that when I set up the same stack on a Windows machine or a MacBook, everything runs fine.

Below I've addded the Dockerfile, and GitHub workflow to show how I built my Docker images for multiple platforms. I've also included a docker compose stack to show how I set up an application stack with the produced images.

I've tried falling back to an older version of Docker Node images which are used as an base, but that had no success.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:20.9-alpine AS build-client

WORKDIR /client

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npx nx build client


FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:20.9-alpine AS build-server

WORKDIR /server

COPY package*.json .

RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps --no-cache python3 make g++ && \
    npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npx nx build server &&  \
    mv packages/server/typeorm dist/database && \
    rm -rf node_modules && \
    npm ci --omit dev && \
    mv packages/server/start.sh package*.json dist && \
    chmod +x dist/start.sh && \
    mv node_modules dist/node_modules && \
    rm -rf dist/node_modules/@dnd-mapp/data && \
    mv dist/data dist/node_modules/@dnd-mapp/data

COPY --from=build-client /client/dist/client dist/client


FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:20.9-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apk add --no-cache bash

COPY --from=build-server server/dist .

ENV DATABASE_FILES_PATH=/usr/src/app/database
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["bash", "/usr/src/app/start.sh"]
```

docker-image.yaml

```yaml
name: Build DnD-Mapp Docker image
on:
    push:
permissions:
    contents: read
    packages: write
env:
    REGISTRY: ghcr.io
    IMAGE_NAME: nonamer777/dnd-mapp
jobs:
    build-docker-image:
        name: Build DnD-Mapp Docker image
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout repository
              uses: actions/checkout@v4
            - name: Set up QEMU
              uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
            - name: Set up Docker Buildx
              uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
              id: docker-buildx
              with:
                  platforms: linux/arm/v6,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/amd64
            - name: Log in to the Container registry
              uses: docker/login-action@v3
              with:
                  registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
                  username: ${{ github.actor }}
                  password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            - name: Extract metadata for Docker
              id: meta
              uses: docker/metadata-action@v5
              with:
                  images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
                  tags: |
                      type=raw,value=dev
                      type=semver,pattern={{version}}
                      type=semver,pattern={{major}}
                      type=semver,pattern={{major}}.{{minor}}
            - name: Build and push Docker image
              uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
              with:
                  context: .
                  file: Dockerfile
                  push: true
                  labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
                  tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
                  platforms: ${{ steps.docker-buildx.outputs.platforms }}
                  cache-from: type=gha
                  cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
```

compose.yaml

```
services:
    dnd-mapp:
        image: ghcr.io/nonamer777/dnd-mapp:dev
        container_name: dnd-mapp
        env_file: .env
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - '8080:8080/tcp'
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy
    db-web-client:
        image: adminer:4
        container_name: mysql-web-client
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - '8888:8080/tcp'
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy 
    db:
        image: mysql:8
        container_name: mysql-database
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - '3306:3306/tcp'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
            MYSQL_USER: db_user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
        networks:
            - private-network
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
            timeout: 10s
            interval: 5s
            retries: 10
```

Comment: If everything was running fine few days ago and you didn’t change anything, please check resource consumption and/or restart docker process.

Comment: The RPi is running on Open Media Vault, with Portainer which I use for managing the Docker containers. It currently has 7 other containers running on it (Not counting the container I want to deploy, but can't because of the error described above) with an average CPU utilization of 6% and memory usage of just under 1 GB of the available 8 GB and plenty of storage space available. Don't think it's a hardware limit issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing the `--platform=$BUILDPLATFORM` parameter from the last stage of the Dockerfile, should any still be interested.